# How to calculate max based on another property in dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

how do I print the name and city of the oldest person in the dictionary?

```
box_dict =  {'name': ['maor', 'gal'], 'song': ['Amsterdam', 'Berlin'], 'age': [20, 35]}
print(max(box_dict["age"]))
```

I can figure out the age of the oldest person, but I want him to print the person's name, not his age.

```
35
```

And all I want is to print the name of the oldest person

```
gal
```

How can you print only the name of the oldest person?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max` function with the `key` argument, which allows you to compare based on particular attribute/index. Try:

```
oldest_person_name = max(zip(box_dict["name"], box_dict["age"]), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

print(oldest_person_name) # gal
```

Comment: I wondered why bother with index in the lambda, why not use unpacking and `key=lambda x, y: y)` but [The ability to unpack tuple parameters was removed in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. It gets the index of the max-age and uses it on the list of names values.

```
mAge = max(box_dict["age"])
prson = box_dict['age'].index(mAge)
mName = box_dict['name'][prson]
```

Comment: This is simple but it works, but not pythonic

Answer (score 0):

Something like so:

```py
d = {"name": ["maor", "gal"], "song": ["Amsterdam" "Berlin"], "age": [20, 35]}
max_index = max(d["name"], key=lambda k: d["age"][d["name"].index(k)])
```